# Attribute in Tag XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm generating a xml file using C#, the file exist, but I need to set an attribute inside of a tag..for exemple:

```
<InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico Id="ID41503">
```

In my file this "Id" stay between the tags

```
<InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico>
     Id="ID41503"
<Rps>
```

My tags are create like this:

```
XmlNode xmlNodeIdentificacaoRps = xmldoc.CreateElement("InfDeclaracaoServico", "IdentificacaoRps", null);
                    xmlNodeIdentificacaoRps.InnerText = "";
                    xmlNodeInfDeclaracaoServico.AppendChild(xmlNodeIdentificacaoRps);
```

I think in the place of "InnerText" I need to put a attribute..but have no idea how can I do it work! Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Attribute` as follows:

```
XmlAttribute attr = xmldoc.CreateAttribute("Id");
attr.Value = "ID41503";

xmlNodeIdentificacaoRps.Attributes.Append(attr);
```

Attributes resides within XML Elements tag, If you place under element(as nested), then you have to use:

```
xmlNodeIdentificacaoRps.InnerText = "Id='ID41503'";
```